# Perform a Full text search on a UUID field in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table with schema that has UUID fields. I need to perform a full text search on both UUID. The `id` field is a primary key and the `type` field is a Liked to a foreign key in another table

```
CREATE TABLE table(
id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
type = Column(ForeignKey("lookups.id"), index=True)
);
```

The lookups table looks something like:

```
 id     | type    |  value  | sys_period
--------------------------------------+--------------------------
uuid_2 | TYPE_2  | value_2 | ["2019-05-30 13:28:37.949718+02",)
uuid_3 | TYPE_3  | value_3 | ["2019-05-30 13:28:37.949718+02",)
uuid_4 | TYPE_4  | value_4 | ["2019-05-30 13:28:37.949718+02",)
```

Comment: What query do you want to run?  "full text search" seems to mean different things to different people.